# Electronic transitions in potassium

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, wavelength, absorption

Potassium atoms in the electronic ground state absorb laser light at 769.9, 766.5, 404.7, 404.4, 344.7 and 344.6 nm. Obviously, these absorption lines exist because an electron is excited from the ground state by the laser light. What I would like to know is how the excited states correspondig to these wavelengths look like. I know that the electronic configuration of the ground state of potassium is

$$1s^2~2s^2~2p^6~3s^2~3p^6~4s^1$$

but I don't quite understand how to find the excited states in this notation which belong to the absorption lines mentioned above. Maybe someone can show me how to do this for this specific atom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are "one-electron" spectra: it is the outer electron that is excited (in first approximation). This leads to Rydberg series: the electron is bound to the ion. The quantum defect is a parameter to take into account interactions with the ionic core.

You can find level designations on the NIST site: http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/lines_form.html
(Type "K I" (K one) for neutral potassium.)

There is also spin-orbit splitting, responsible for the lines that come in doublets.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this wasn't quite what I am looking for. Maybe I just don't understand this whole thing, but how do I determine to which excited states the outer electron can go?

Comment: @MeMeansMe The outer electron can be in any orbital beyond $4s$. There are the dipole selection rules, so absorption from the ground state will only be to $np$ states.